# emberjs transitionTo not rendering model list

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

UPDATE: Ok. I solved this.. I think it was because I was rendering the new client template into the application template in ClientsNewRoute(see below). My understanding(assumption) is that it was not operating within the context of the client model because it was initially rendering the new form into the application template then treating that as the parent while attempting to "transitionTo" the clients list view.

I have an /clients view that lists all of the clients when doing a complete refresh but after adding a new client from a form and using transitionTo it will not render the list. The logs show that the transitionTo is successful but I can't get the list to populate unless I am doing a complete refresh of the clients/ route. The backend is returning 200 with a complete model object. It may be because the model hook is not being called when transitioning from a subroute. Any ideas?

router.js

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('clients', function(){
    this.route('new');
  });
  this.resource('client', { path: '/clients/:client_id' }, function(){
    this.route('edit');
  });

  this.resource('managers', function(){
    this.route('new');
  });
  this.resource('manager', { path: '/managers/:manager_id' }, function(){
    this.route('edit');
  });
  this.resource('projects', function(){
    this.route('new');
  });
  this.resource('project', { path: '/projects/:project_id' }, function(){
    this.route('edit');
  });
});
```

clients.route:

```
App.ClientsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function(){
    return this.store.find('client');
  }

});
```

clients/new_route.js:

```
App.ClientsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render("clients/new", { 
        into: "application",
        outlet: "main"
})},

model: function(){
    return this.store.createRecord('client');
},
actions: {
    create: function(client){
        var route = this;
        client.save().then(function() {
            route.transitionTo('clients');
        }, function() {
            console.log('fail');
        });
    } 
  } 
});
```

Thanks

EDIT:

client/new.handlebars:

```
<form {{action 'create' this on="submit"}} >

{{#if isSaving }}
saving record...
{{/if}}


<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h2>New Client</h2>

        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr> <td> Company Name </td> <td>{{input class="form-control" type="text" value=company_name}} </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> First Name </td> <td> {{input class="form-control" type="text" value=first_name}} </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> Last Name </td> <td> {{input class="form-control" type="text" value=last_name}} </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> Email </td> <td> {{input class="form-control" type="text" value=email}} </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> Phone </td> <td> {{input class="form-control" type="text" value=phone}} </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> Description </td> <td> {{textarea class="form-control" value=description}} </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> Address </td> <td> {{input class="form-control" type="text" value=street_address}} </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> City </td> <td> {{input class="form-control" type="text" value=city}} </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> State </td> <td> {{input class="form-control" type="text" value=state}} </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> Zipcode </td> <td> {{input class="form-control" type="text" value=zip}} </td> </tr>

        </table>
        <button>Create</button>

    </form>
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

clients.handlebars:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2"></div>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <h2>Clients</h2>

    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
        {{#each}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{#link-to 'client' this}} {{company_name}}     {{/link-to}}</td>
            <td>    {{ first_name}} {{last_name}} </td>
            <td>  {{ email }} </td>
            <td>  {{phone}} </td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}

    </table>

    <p> {{#link-to 'clients.new'}}Create a new Client{{/link-to}}</p>
</div> 
<div class="col-md-2">o</div>
```

Log info:

```
Transitioned into 'clients.new' ember.js?body=1:3499
Transition #1: TRANSITION COMPLETE. ember.js?body=1:3499
Attempting transition to clients ember.js?body=1:3499
Transition #2: clients.index: calling beforeModel hook ember.js?body=1:3499
Transition #2: clients.index: calling deserialize hook ember.js?body=1:3499
Transition #2: clients.index: calling afterModel hook ember.js?body=1:3499
Transition #2: Resolved all models on destination route; finalizing transition. ember.js?body=1:3499
Could not find "clients.index" template or view. Nothing will be rendered Object {fullName: "template:clients.index"} ember.js?body=1:3499
Transitioned into 'clients.index' ember.js?body=1:3499
Transition #2: TRANSITION COMPLETE
```

The template that is rendered when I request the route directly is clients.handlebars and sits in the root of the templates/ directory. It doesn't have an outlet, it contains the #each loop  that displays the table of clients.

Comment: Can you post the handlebars? Controller if anything important?

Comment: You need to provide the information for the `ClientsRoute`, since that is the area with the problem. Also, are these defined as `routes` or `resources` on the map?

Comment: Added routes for clients and clients/new as well as handlebars templates. The only outlet here is in my application.handlebars file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.. I think it was because I was rendering the new client template into the application template in ClientsNewRoute(see below). My understanding(assumption) is that it was not operating within the context of the client model because it was initially rendering the new form into the application template then treating that as the parent while attempting to "transitionTo" the clients list view. See above for details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have your map structured something like:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('clients', function(){
        this.route('new');
    });
});
```

And your issue is that when transitioning from `clients/new` to `clients`, the model isn't being reloaded.  Is this correct?

If so, try creating another Route:

```
App.ClientsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('client');
    }
});
```

Comment: That's correct. I added my route.js file above as well. I'll try that.

Comment: I added some log info as well.

Comment: Yeah, that definitely looks like you just need to add the index route!  Have you tried it?

Comment: Still no luck. How should my templates be set up? I don't have a clients/index.handlebars template now as you can see above. I don't need one for the initial view when I go right to clients/ but it seems to be looking for one judging from the logs.

Comment: I'm starting to see a bigger underlying problem here;  Your map structure and outlet structure are not matched.  It's ok to do that, of course, but requires quite a bit of extra work to get things working correctly (which is the underlying issue you're running into).  Is there a reason you set your map and outlets in a different pattern (e.g.;  `clients/new` is rendering into `application:main` outlet rather than the `{{outlet}}` tag within `clients` where it would go by default)

Comment: This was my first foray into ember so I ended up doing that to get the resource patterns the way I wanted them. I'm sure I approached it the wrong way. I'll try to reconfigure that stuff per your suggestion.

Comment: If you didn't do that for a specific reason, the easiest solution would be to simply move the `this.route('new')` line from your map up to the root level and mark it as a `resource` instead of a `route`.  You'll obviously need to adjust your `link-to` and `transitionTo` to match that pattern as well.

Comment: would doing that affect the ability to have that 'new' route apply only to the client resource so I can have creation forms for other models eg: projects/new contacts/new etc?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47998/discussion-between-gravityplanx-and-errata)

Comment: So far this is not solved but I am fairly sure the routes and templates are set up in a way that should work. thanks to @gravityplanx for that.